# Google Maps API - Accessing the Create a List (add, update, delete) Lists

Tags: google-maps-urls

I was using the Google Maps URL API to Create a map with a list of waypoints
(See here [Google Maps Platform - Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started))

But, the maps url limits the number of addresses listed to 10 addresses. I need to be able to add more than 10.

I then looked at Lists and adding the addresses to the list. This will work for our requirements but I don't see any way to access the List in any Google Maps API.

Basically I want to create/modify the List of places described [here](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/7280933?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#).

How do I create/modify List in Google Maps? (URL, API, Javascript, etc...)